# What should I do next

Tags: meditation

After I sit for about 45 minutes my mind becomes very a lot more still and there is barely any wondering thought. If there is thought I notice it very quickly and it disappears. It feels like awareness becomes wider and I'm aware of everything at once without losing mindfulness of the breath. I then begin to wonder what to do next. I usually just enjoy the calm and serenity but after a while I open my eyes and get on with the day.  Sometimes I feel bored which I note.
Is there something else I can do next?

Comment: `After I sit for about 45 minutes my mind becomes very a lot more still and` How long have you had this experience(45 min sit and stillness)?

Answer (score 0):

What was reached after 45 minutes is ideally the starting point of every meditation session rather than the end. What is done next is to maintain equanimity towards the calm and serenity and to develop/deepen this calm and serenity via equanimity & non-attachment.

Wandering thoughts are called "distracting thoughts" in the sutta teachings (MN 20). Contemplation of mind (cittanupassana) in the sutta teachings is not related to thoughts. If boredom arises, this should be experienced with equanimity until the boredom dissolves into a buoyant clarity.

The specific sutta teachings (MN 10; MN 118) say the ultimate goal of meditation is to be free from greed & dejection towards the world of experience. Therefore, when calm and serenity occur, prevent/abandon greed arising towards it. When boredom occurs, prevent/abandon dejection arising towards it.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this